# How to use requirejs to import web3

Tags: web3js, requirejs

I want to use web3 from **loginmain.js** file. My project hierarchy looks like:

```
Project/
  www/
    login.html
    js/
      login.js
      app/
        loginmain.js
      lib/
        jquery.js
        web3.js
  tools/
```

my **loginmain.js** file :

```
define(function (require) {
var $ = require('jquery'),
    Web3 = require('web3'),
    lib = require('./lib'),
    controller = require('./controller/c1'),
    model = require('./model/m1');

//A fabricated API to show interaction of
//common and specific pieces.
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
console.log(web3);
controller.setModel(model);
$(function () {
    controller.render(lib.getBody());
});});
```

I get the following **Error**

```
TypeError: Web3 is undefined
```

Any idea how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

I propose you to read about how to load an external js library in a js file : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

this issue doesn't have a direct relation with web3.js